# How to remotely debug linux module using GDB?

Tags: linux, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver, kgdb

I want to debug linux module remotely. So, linux module is loaded on VM-A and I want to debug that module on VM-B using GDB. I have gone through QEMU way but I don't want that because the target VM-A is unrelated and doesn't related to same host. Maybe, KGDB is a way but I am not getting proper steps to debug that way.

Also, if KGDB uses serial ports. Do we need to connect those ports using cable hardware or something like that? as we don't want that :
This is a scenario - VM-A has loaded module which traces block devices. VM-B has GDB which will do remote debugging and we can add breakpoints and then step by step execution.